# Issue with hidden div with responsive slider in a wordpress website

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

So basicly I want to have 2 buttons (one for map and one for recent posts). I implemented it by making jQuery script for the hiding/showing the divs as it follows:

```
    <div id="main-choice" style="height:100%; width:100%;">
    <button class="buttons" id="button-region">News by regions</button>
    <button class="buttons" id="button-latest-news">Latest news</button> 
    </div>

        <div class="hide" id="world-map-chosen" style="width:100%;"><button id="back-to-choice-1">Back</button>
            <?php build_i_world_map(1); ?></div>
        <div class="hide" id="latest-news-chosen" style="height:400px; width:100%;"><button id="back-to-choice-2">Back</button> 
            <?php echo get_new_royalslider(1); ?> </div>    


    <script>
$("#world-map-chosen").hide();
$("#latest-news-chosen").hide();
$('#button-region').click(function() {
  $('#main-choice').fadeOut('slow', function() {
      $("#world-map-chosen").fadeIn("slow");
  });    
});
$('#button-latest-news').click(function() {
   $('#main-choice').fadeOut('slow', function() {
   $("#latest-news-chosen").fadeIn("slow", function(){
      fireOnResizeEvent();
  });
  });
  });
$('#back-to-choice-1').click(function() {
  $('#world-map-chosen').fadeOut('slow', function() {
      $("#main-choice").fadeIn("slow");
  });   
 });
 $('#back-to-choice-2').click(function() {
   $('#latest-news-chosen').fadeOut('slow', function() {
      $("#main-choice").fadeIn("slow");
  });   
 });
 </script>
       </div>
```

and in the head tag:

```
<script language="JavaScript" >
function fireOnResizeEvent() {
 var width, height;

 if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {
  width  = document.body.offsetWidth;
  height = document.body.offsetHeight;
 } else {
  width  = window.outerWidth;
  height = window.outerHeight;
 }

 window.resizeTo(width - 1, height);
 window.resizeTo(width + 1, height);
}

window.onresize = function() {
 alert("Resized!");
}
</script>
```

My issue is that the slider and the map are taking the hidden state size and not refreshing when shown by the script.

As you can see i tried to include a function in the jQuery that resize the window after the load, but without luck.

Both the functions for loading the map and the slider are working correctly.

Could you please help me solve this one by helping me fix this code or give me some ideas how should i make it?

Comment: It looks like a CSS issue. If you have both map and slider divs visible from the start, are they the correct size?

Comment: yes. I tried loading only the map and slider and they were both working fine.

Comment: Do you use Firebug or Chrome Devtools to check CSS? When those divs are visible they will take the properties specified by matching CSS selectors so you should be able to see why they are not the size you expect.

Comment: The only error Chrome Devtools show is "wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.2.2:4 Uncaught TypeError: f.className.indexOf is not a functiong.observe.childList @ wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.2.2:4" but it is not related to this issue (it's the map so called responsiveness which is not good implemented), because even when i remove the map the issue with the slider alone stays. The interesting thing is that the slider frame is fitted in the div but the images taken from the recent posts are small until the user resize the window. After that they take the new window size and work ok.